# Bar Button Item image size

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have a view-controller that is embedded in a navigation controller. I want to set the top-right bar button item of the navigation-bar to a custom image:

[image]

I do this in storyboard (pictured above), however you will notice how small the image appears. And here it is when running:

[image]

The actual size of the image I am using is not that small. I just can't seem to figure out how to get this image to appear larger within the top-right bar button item.

Answer (score -1):

This actually did turn out to be an issue with the size of my images; they were too small. I was miscalculating as I exported from Sketch; had to export them about double the size I was before.